# Jquery is not identifying custom anchor tag attributes

Tags: jquery, html

I have a jquery function that is building dynamic html code from calling a php script the html is output using

```
 $('ul.special-list').append("<li><a href='#' class=restaurantItem  restaurant= '" + item.estName + "' adddress='" + item.estAddr + "'><img src= " + item.img_link + 
            " width='60' height='60' alt='" + item.estName + "'><div class='img-det'><strong class='title'> " + item.title + " </strong><p> " + item.desc_short +
            " <br>Expires: " + item.expiry_date + " </p><em class='price'>" + item.price + "</em></div></a><a href='dealDetail.html?id=" + item.id +
            "' class='det-link'>Detail</a>");
```

I then have a function that is called on doument.ready the function is called correctly but the value of the custom anchor tag - restaurant is not shown with an alert.

```
$('ul.special-list').on('click', 'a.restaurantItem', function (event) {

    event.preventDefault();
    alert($(this).attr('address'));
 }
```

The alert shows undefined even though when i inspect the element in chrome the element restaurant on the  tag has a value.

Any help would be great, im quite new to Jquery so any help would be appreciated.

Many Thanks

Comment: your class name should be in quotes on the appended a just glancing at it

Comment: where abouts is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, its basically because in your **HTML string** the attribute name is **adddress** and you are trying to access the attribute **address**.

 Change `adddress='" + item.estAddr + "'` to `address='" + item.estAddr + "'`.
 
Also consider adding quotes for **class**: `class="restaurantItem"`

Comment: Im so stupid, i have been looking at this for hours and its something silly like this, im so angry at myself ! Well thats programming for you i suppose. Thank you for showing me my error.

Answer (score 1):

The class attribute may be affecting it like John B mentioned, because class accepts multiple, space-separated values. The space after the class attribute may look to us like it's finished declaring classes, but Chrome seems to interpret the rest of the tag as more classes.

It could be that jQuery isn't properly handling those attributes because they aren't all standard. Typically, non-standard attributes should be written as `data-address=''` rather than just `address=''`. Once you switch to that format, you can access the `data-address` attribute using `attr('data-address')` or in newer jQuery versions with `data('address')`.